# How to show Image editing screen with custom camera overlay with takePicture method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application I have to show a custom camera overlay.It is showing perfectly.
On that view , I have a button which hits the method `takePicture` which is responsible for capturing image from camera.

My problem is after I shoot a photo, I need to show the image editing screen as it is shown when we used the default camera.

Please help me how to show the image editing screen which appears after taking image from camera when the camera overlay is nil but in my case it is necessary to customize the camera overlay.

So please suggest me how to show the image preview(editing)screen with custom camera overlay view.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)presentCamera{    
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    }
    else{ //camera not available
        //promt the user about camera's unavailability
        return;
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated: YES];
}
```

pay attention to `cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already mentioned in my question that it works with default camera but when we show some custom overlay on camera then it does not.

Comment: Did you find a way of doing this? I have the same problem.